# Google places api Administrative_Area_level strange wrong format?

Tags: ios, json, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using google places api to retrive information about some cities that users can select with an autocomplete UItableview. 
My first Request give me a list of cities and locality,starting from the search string:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=salo&types=(cities)&key=APIKEY

From the results list i take the place_id of "Salò" a city in Italy. With this id the second request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJdf_ajleOgUcRGniBFh7H884&key=APIKEY

And this is the resulting json:

```
           {
  "html_attributions" : [],
"result" : {
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "Salò",
        "short_name" : "Salò",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Salo'",
        "short_name" : "Salo'",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Brescia",
        "short_name" : "BS",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Lombardia",
        "short_name" : "Lombardia",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Italia",
        "short_name" : "IT",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
  ],
  "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eSalò\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eBS\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eItalia\u003c/span\u003e",
  "formatted_address" : "Salò BS, Italia",
  "geometry" : {
     "location" : {
        "lat" : 45.60839199999999,
        "lng" : 10.5104769
     },
     "viewport" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 45.6146863,
           "lng" : 10.5464998
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 45.59572439999999,
           "lng" : 10.4992233
        }
     }
  },
  "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
  "id" : "f505830b9f7b6886f119df1b07bec0a6785940c7",
  "name" : "Salò",
  "place_id" : "ChIJdf_ajleOgUcRGniBFh7H884",
  "reference" : "CnRtAAAAP9oklxjP8yqebLXhyFK0PM7l_w8zD8eBdNszf67rPHlckKnrhhs66eXZTYHfBiEizetRM8m7e8qxM6otVCX0QvxQ4jXgSv4VcH7NY2ZbYysboNplu8vaFs_BhITJ1MQJ-TunE9L-r1nBavhMLQRKNBIQqsKl1vt_pyqE_7Ow1aXp-hoU9jreecvh94V2ZpHT1JB-DxfoZEI",
  "scope" : "GOOGLE",
  "types" : [ "locality", "political" ],
  "url" : "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Sal%C3%B2+BS,+Italia&ftid=0x47818e578edaff75:0xcef3c71e1681781a",
  "vicinity" : "Salò"
},
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

From this json i need to extract the value from administrative_area_level_3 but i see something strange in accent, why the locality long_name value is "Salò" while the administrative_area_level_3 long_name value is "Salo'" ? What's the sense of this behaviour? In this way the administrative_area_level_3 results in the uilabel of my app as "Salo\'" even with utf8 encode/decode process...

Comment: I get another response from the 2nd link(both `Salò` for `locality` and `administrative_area_level_3`)

Comment: Maybe the apikey? Or the region of the user that make the request?

Comment: Seems to be the user-region, when I set the language-parameter to `it` I get the wrong format. I guess it's just wrong data, you may [report it](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Geocoding%20API%20-%20Bug).

Comment: thanks i can mark as correct answer if you write it